# What is the fastest way to find out if a string ends with another string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

What is the best rewrite of this method to speed it up?

```
public static bool EndsWith(string line, string term)
{

    bool rb = false;

    int lengthOfTerm = term.Length;

    string endOfString = StringHelpers.RightString(line, lengthOfTerm);

    if (StringHelpers.AreEqual(term, endOfString))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        rb = false;
    }

    if (line == term)
    {
        rb = true;
    }

    return rb;

}
```

Comment: This question may win for having an accuracy of 100% across all answers (at least at the time of writing).

Comment: thanks for the unanimous help everyone, I looked through string's members and guess I can throw out my StartsWith and PadWithZeros helper functions as well :-)

Comment: IsNullOrEmpty is my favourite

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe I am missing the point completely, but I would spontaneously go for the [`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) method.

Comment: +1, you're unlikely to get it any faster than Microsoft can in the core of the language.

Comment: I am currently refactoring some helper methods that I made back in 2002 at which time there was no .EndsWith in C# 1 or I didn't know about it, thanks. Funny it has the same name.

Comment: @Edward; whoever wrote that method sure did the homework in the naming department. Should facilitate refactoring, I guess.

Comment: It's been there since the beginning.  When making a StringHelpers class, it probably helps to read through String's members.

Comment: And when making an FAQ on condescension, check Matthew Flaschen's comments. :D

Answer (score 6):

You may want to drop the method rather than rewrite it...

```
public static bool EndsWith(string line, string term)
{
  return line.EndsWith(term);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you use the .NET builtin in string.Endwith() method?

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use the standard string.EndsWith() function??

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you aren't using the build in String.EndsWith method? I imagine that will be the fastest solution most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

line.EndsWidth(term)